# Error in desmos while computing $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx $

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software, desmos

When I was computing this integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx $ on Desmos I was getting correct answer as $\sqrt \pi.$

But when I started to change the limits of the integration something weird started happening

[image: Check this out]

can anyone tell me what is the issue?

Comment: It's broken? When software fails, we can't often tell you why it is failing - that is up to the software's author. I'd guess that the first integral is one it "knows," but the second one it is trying to do numerically, and is failing.

Comment: Without knowing exactly how Desmos works, here's a guess. An integral of the form $\int_{-\infty}^Nf(x)dx$ with finite $N>0$ can't be estimated by the trapezium rule without first transforming $x$ so the integration range is an interval. Once that happens, all but the rightmost sampled values of the new variable will be where the original $x$ is a large negative number, while the rightmost might be $x=N$. For $f=e^{-x^2}$, all such sampling will make $f$ small.

Comment: It is probably a tanh-sinh quadrature artifact